# Duvida em Javascript Map e findIndex

Tags: javascript, json

Estou tendo dificuldade ao transformar dados em json.

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo que pega os elementos do meu payload e imprimir para json.

```
const _ = require('lodash')

let prod = [];
let stores = [];

module.exports = async (data) => {
    data.map(Element => {

    let dado = {}
    dado.code = Element.COD_PROD,
    dado.stores = stores
    prod.push(Object.assign({}, dado))
})


data.map(Element => {

    let dado = {};
    let a = [];
    let V_MESES;

    V_MESES = Element.MESES

    a = V_MESES.split(",");


    let pos = _.findIndex(stores, entr => {
        return entr.code === Element.COD_LOJA
    })
    if (pos === -1) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

            dado.code_prod = Element.COD_PROD,
                dado.code = Element.COD_LOJA,
                dado.value = `${a[i]}`,
                stores.push(Object.assign({}, dado));
        }
    }
})

return prod
```

}

payload:

```
[
[
{
    "COD_LOJA": 10,
    "ANO": 2016,
    "COD_PROD": 1,
    "MESES": "1.00,0.00,2.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00"
},
{
    "COD_LOJA": 10,
    "ANO": 2016,
    "COD_PROD": 2,
    "MESES": "2.00,3.00,4.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00"

}
```

]
]

No Output :

```
[
{
    "code": 1,
    "stores": [
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "2.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "3.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "code": 2,
    "stores": [
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "2.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "3.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "1.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        },
        {
            "code_prod": 1,
            "code": 10,
            "value": "0.00"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Minha duvida é como faço para o produto 2 pegar os dados pertencente a ele? Pois o produto 2 imprime os dados do produto um.

Answer (score 0):

Você declarou um array `stores` e atribuiu esse mesmo array para ambos `scores` do output.

Como arrays são passados por referência, ambos arrays são os mesmos, portanto quando você adiciona um item num array, ele reflete no outro.

Tem mais erros no código, não tem nenhuma razão para essa função ser `async`,  você utiliza `map` ao invés de `forEach` para iterar sobre arrays, esse `findIndex` não faz sentido nenhum no contexto do seu exemplo. Se for para seguir a sua lógica, acredito que depois de arrumar, seu código ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
function refatorar(data) {
  let prod = []; // prod é declarado no escopo da função, não do módulo

  for (let elem of data) {
    let dado = {};
    dado.code = elem.COD_PROD;
    dado.stores = []; // um "stores" novo para cada dado

    let v_meses = elem.MESES.split(',');

    for (let mes of v_meses) {
      let store = {};
      store.code_prod = elem.COD_PROD;
      store.code = elem.COD_LOJA;
      store.value = mes;

      dado.stores.push(store);
    }

    prod.push(dado);
  }

  return prod;
}


const data = [{
  "COD_LOJA": 10,
  "ANO": 2016,
  "COD_PROD": 1,
  "MESES": "1.00,0.00,2.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00"
}, {
  "COD_LOJA": 10,
  "ANO": 2016,
  "COD_PROD": 2,
  "MESES": "2.00,3.00,4.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00"
}]

console.log(refatorar(data));
```

Claro, você também pode fazer o devido uso do método `map` para gerar novos arrays:

```js
function refatorar(data) {
  return data.map(elem => ({
    code: elem.COD_PROD,
    stores: elem.MESES.split(',').map(mes => ({
      code_prod: elem.COD_PROD,
      code: elem.COD_LOJA,
      value: mes
    }))
  }))
}

const data = [{
  "COD_LOJA": 10,
  "ANO": 2016,
  "COD_PROD": 1,
  "MESES": "1.00,0.00,2.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00"
}, {
  "COD_LOJA": 10,
  "ANO": 2016,
  "COD_PROD": 2,
  "MESES": "2.00,3.00,4.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,3.00,0.00,0.00,1.00,0.00,0.00"
}];

console.log(refatorar(data));
```